# Uploading image withV4Signature() defined with MD5 hash is permitted, even though hashes don't match

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

I'm using the Google Cloud Storage Java library to create a signed URL with the withV4Signature() method, it seems to work well. However, I was under the impression that if you specify the MD5 hash of an image when creating the signed URL, any attempt to upload an image with that URL that did NOT match the specified MD5 hash would be rejected.

This does not seem to be the case...As I can specify any MD5 hash I want in the "setMD5()" method, and Google storage will accept my uploaded file.

```
    BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(
            BlobId.of("mybucket, "myobject.jpeg"))
            .setMd5("some-Random-Md5-Hash-Unrelated-To-The-Image")
            .setContentType("image/jpeg")
            .build();

    URL url = storage.signUrl(blobInfo,
            30,
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            Storage.SignUrlOption.withV4Signature(),
            Storage.SignUrlOption.signWith(myServiceAccountCredentials),
            Storage.SignUrlOption.withMd5(),
            Storage.SignUrlOption.httpMethod(com.google.cloud.storage.HttpMethod.PUT),
            Storage.SignUrlOption.withContentType());
```

And then, using an image with a totally different MD5 hash:

```
curl -X PUT --upload-file myobject.jpeg "https://storage.googleapis.com/mybucket/myobject.jpeg?X-Goog-Algorithm=GOOG4-RSA-SHA256&X-Goog-Credential=[My Service Account Credential]%2F20210501%2Fauto%2Fstorage%2Fgoog4_request&X-Goog-Date=20210501T035401Z&X-Goog-Expires=30&X-Goog-SignedHeaders=host&X-Goog-Signature=[Google API Provided Signature]"
```

Google Storage accepts this image upload without complaint. My question is, does anyone else have experience with explicitly setting the MD5 hash on Signed URLs for the Google Storage API and can see where I've gone wrong? Perhaps I've misunderstood the nature of this feature and encoding an MD5 restriction into a singed URL just isn't possible?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but by looking at the description of `Storage.SignUrlOption.withMd5()` here at the [docs](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-storage/latest/com/google/cloud/storage/Storage.SignUrlOption.html#withMd5--):

> Use it if signature should include the blob's md5. When used, users of the signed URL **should include the blob's md5 with their request**.

What's missing on your code is a [canonical header](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication/canonical-requests#about-headers) on your Signed URL. Adding `Content-MD5` header to your Signed URL ensures that any wrong MD5 hash or missing header on the request won't execute the upload request.

Note that **you must convert your MD5 hash from Hex to Base64**. Here's an updated version of your code:

```
Map <String, String> extHeaders = new HashMap<String, String>(); // create map header
extHeaders.put("Content-MD5", "BASE64_MD5");  

BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(
  BlobId.of("my-bucket", "myobject.jpeg"))
    .setMd5("BASE64_MD5")
    .setContentType("image/jpeg")
    .build();

URL url = storage.signUrl(blobInfo,
  30,
  TimeUnit.SECONDS,
  Storage.SignUrlOption.withV4Signature(),
  Storage.SignUrlOption.signWith(myServiceAccountCredentials),
  Storage.SignUrlOption.withMd5(),
  Storage.SignUrlOption.withExtHeaders(extHeaders), // attach the header as canonical header
  Storage.SignUrlOption.httpMethod(com.google.cloud.storage.HttpMethod.PUT),
  Storage.SignUrlOption.withContentType());
```

Then finally, your `curl` request:

```
curl -X PUT --header "Content-MD5: BASE64_MD5" --upload-file myobject.jpeg "SIGNED_URL"
```